# Encountering a TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when creating an SGD algorithm

Tags: python, while-loop, floating-point, typeerror, stochastic-gradient

```
# We first define the observations as a list and then also as a table for the experienced worker's performance.

Observation1 = [2.0, 6.0, 2.0]
Observation2 = [1.0, 5.0, 7.0]
Observation3 = [5.0, 2.0, 1.0]
Observation4 = [2.0, 3.0, 8.0]
Observation5 = [4.0, 4.0, 0.0]
ObservationTable = [
                    Observation1,
                    Observation2,
                    Observation3,
                    Observation4,
                    Observation5
                    ]

# Then we define our learning rate, number of observations, and the epoch counters we will be utilizing (10, 100, and 1000).

LearningRate = 0.01
ObservationCounter = 5
EpochVersion1 = 10
EpochVersion2 = 100
EpochVersion3 = 1000

# Thus, we are now ready to define the Stochastic Gradient Descent Algorithm:

def StochasticGradientDescent(EpochCounter):
    Theta0 = 10.0
    Theta1 = 0.0
    Theta2 = -1.0

    while (EpochCounter != 0):

        ObservationCounter = 5

        while (ObservationCounter >= 0):

            Theta0_Old = float(Theta0)
            Theta1_Old = float(Theta1)
            Theta2_Old = float(Theta2)

            n = 5 - ObservationCounter
            x = ObservationTable [n]
            x0 = float(x[0])
            x1 = float(x[1])
            x2 = float(x[2])

            Theta0_New = Theta0_Old - LearningRate*[(Theta0_Old+Theta1_Old*float(x0)+Theta2_Old*float(x1))-float(x2)]
            Theta1_New = Theta1_Old - LearningRate*[(Theta0_Old+Theta1_Old*float(x0)+Theta2_Old*float(x1))-float(x2)]*float(x0)
            Theta2_New = Theta2_Old - LearningRate*[(Theta0_Old+Theta1_Old*float(x0)+Theta2_Old*float(x1))-float(x2)]*float(x1)

            print(Theta0_New, Theta1_New, Theta2_New)
            ObservationCounter -= 1

        else:
            EpochCounter -= 1
            if (EpochCounter == 0):
               print(Theta0_New, Theta1_New, Theta2_New)


StochasticGradientDescent(int(EpochVersion1))
```

The code outputs the TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. I have already converted the values into floats at each possible step, but the error still remains. The key lines are mostly those relating to the definition function for the SGD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know very much about stochastic gradient descent but there are two improvements that I spot in your code.

Firstly, the error is caused because you try to multiply a float with a list and add that to a float. This is fixed by using round brackets instead of square:

```
            Theta0_New = Theta0_Old - LearningRate*((Theta0_Old+Theta1_Old*float(x0)+Theta2_Old*float(x1))-float(x2))
            Theta1_New = Theta1_Old - LearningRate*((Theta0_Old+Theta1_Old*float(x0)+Theta2_Old*float(x1))-float(x2))*float(x0)
            Theta2_New = Theta2_Old - LearningRate*((Theta0_Old+Theta1_Old*float(x0)+Theta2_Old*float(x1))-float(x2))*float(x1)
```

Secondly your while loop should end one iteration early, otherwise you will get an error when you try to access `ObservationTable[5]`.

Therefore change your while loop to:

```
while (ObservationCounter >= 1):
```

output:

```
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.98 -0.04 -1.12
10.02 0.02 -0.9
9.93 -0.35000000000000003 -1.1400000000000001
10.01 0.02 -0.97
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
9.94 -0.24 -1.24
```

Final remark:
You do not need to convert EpochVersion1 to an integer: `int(EpochVersion1)`.
It is already an integer when you declare it as `EpochVersion1 = 10`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem has been fixed.